# Still confused with BeforeFieldInit

Tags: c#

According to MSDN:

> BeforeFieldInit specifies that calling static methods of the type does not force the
>   system to initialize the type.

In addition to this (IMHO), the existence of static ctor will disable `BeforeFieldInit`.

Now I want to check whether the type is not initialized if I invoke static method while my class has no static ctor as follows.

```
using System;

namespace Static
{
    class Foo
    {
        public Foo(string arg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Foo's ctor called by {0}.", arg);
        }
    }

    class Goo
    {
        Foo f2 = new Foo("Goo's instance field.");

        //static Goo() 
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine("Goo's static ctor."); 
        //}

        static Foo f = new Foo("Goo's static field.");

        public Goo() 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("Goo's default ctor.");
        }

        public static void Display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Goo's static method.");
        }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Goo.Display();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

And the output is as follows,

```
Foo's ctor called by Goo's static field..
Goo's static method.
```

### Questions

Why does the static field still get initialized when I invoke a static method? It seems to be inconsistent with MSDN says above.

Comment: Your static field is a member of Goo, not Foo.  And Goo most certainly has a static constructor, required to get that field initialized.

Comment: @HansPassant: Yes. Of course I know that the static field of type `Foo` named `f` is a member for `Goo`. But why does it still get initialized? In my understanding invoking the static method `Display` does not force Operating System to intialize the class `Goo`. Note that the static ctor has been disabled by comments so `BeforeFieldInit` should be active. What is wrong with my argumentation?

Comment: Nothing is "disabled", Goo still has a static constructor.  The C# compiler auto-generated one.  Run ildasm.exe to see it.

Comment: @HansPassant: Sorry. I just need a confirmation. Whenever a class has static members and we have no an explicit static ctor, the compiler will generate the static ctor automatically. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Don't ask me for confirmation, run ildasm.exe so you can see it for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

1. Goo has a static constructor(created by complier).
2. In CLI spec:If marked BeforeFieldInit then the type’s initializer method is
       executed at, or sometime before, first access to any static field
       defined for that type.